# Yammer REST API > Retain authentication details

Tags: rest, yammer

I have created a Yammer app wherein the user is able to make posts and obtain messages using an open graph feed. The user is asked to authorize the Yammer app the first time he/she logs in, in order to obtain an access token. My question is, is it possible that the user does not have to login every time he/she uses the app, in order to obtain this token?

Currently, the container where the feed is supposed to show, shows a "Login to Yammer" button. Only after the login, is the feed visible.

Is there a way to automatically login the user in the background without using impersonation? (If an encrypted version of the username and password is stored in the system.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't log in the user without either the user interacting to authorize the app, or the authorization being performed through impersonation. You can use the [setAuthToken()](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/) method from the JavaScript SDK for Yammer to inject an existing token, even if you are doing the full impersonation laid out in the linked article.